# XML domains(lookups): Prevent duplicates between domains

Tags: oracle, database-design, xml, duplication

**Background:**

I have some GIS [domains](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/domain-storage-oracle.htm) (a.k.a. lookup tables) that are stored in an XML column in a single [system table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/overview-geodatabase-system-tables.htm). The domains are not directly accessible via SQL, so I use a view to extract the values. I combine the domains into a single view so that I can use them in a query for reporting.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(EXTRACTVALUE(CodedValues.COLUMN_VALUE, 'CodedValue/Code'),1,255) AS Code
    ,SUBSTR(EXTRACTVALUE(CodedValues.COLUMN_VALUE, 'CodedValue/Name'),1,255) AS Description
    ,I.NAME as Domain_Name
FROM
    SDE.GDB_ITEMS_VW I
JOIN 
    SDE.GDB_ITEMTYPES IT
    ON I.Type = IT.UUID,
    TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(XMLType(Definition).Extract('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue'))) CodedValues
WHERE
    I.NAME IN('ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK'
             ,'ACTIVITY_SEWER'
             ,'ACTIVITY_ROAD')

USER1.ACTIVITY_COMBINED_VW
+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
|      CODE       |          DESCRIPTION          |      DOMAIN       |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| CONSTR_S        | CONSTRUCT NEW SIDEWALK        | ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK |
| RECON_S         | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SIDEWALK | ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| CONSTR_SEW      | CONSTRUCT NEW SEWER           | ACTIVITY_SEWER    |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| CONSTR_ROAD     | CONSTRUCT NEW ROAD            | ACTIVITY_ROAD     |
| RECON_ROAD      | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING ROAD     | ACTIVITY_ROAD     |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
```

The report is based on the `CAPITAL_PROJECTS` table:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| PROJECT_ID |  ACTIVITY   |   COST    |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
|         01 | RECON_S     | 5,000,000 |
|         02 | CONSTR_SEW  | 6,000,000 |
|         03 | CONSTR_ROAD | 7,000,000 |
|         04 | RECON_ROAD  | 8,000,000 |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I have a report query that grabs the `DESCRIPTION` from the `ACTIVITY_COMBINED_VW` view:

```
SELECT 
    CAPITAL_PROJECTS.PROJECT_ID
   ,ACTIVITY_COMBINED_VW.DESCRIPTION
   ,CAPITAL_PROJECTS.COST
FROM 
    USER1.CAPITAL_PROJECTS 
LEFT JOIN 
    USER1.ACTIVITY_COMBINED_VW 
    ON CAPITAL_PROJECTS.ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY_COMBINED_VW.CODE;

USER1.REPORT_VW
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| PROJECT_ID |        DESCRIPTION            |   COST    |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|         01 | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SIDEWALK | 5,000,000 |
|         02 | CONSTRUCT NEW SEWER           | 6,000,000 |
|         03 | CONSTRUCT NEW ROAD            | 7,000,000 |
|         04 | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING ROAD     | 8,000,000 |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Problem:**

While the GIS application **does** prevent users from entering duplicate values within a single domain, the application does **not** prevent users from entering duplicate values **between different domains**.

For example, it is entirely possible that a user could accidently enter a `RECON_S` CODE in both the `ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK` domain and the `ACTIVITY_SEWER` domain:

```
              +-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
              |      CODE       |          DESCRIPTION          | DOMAIN            |
              +-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
              | CONSTR_S        | CONSTRUCT NEW SIDEWALK        | ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK | 
Existing ---> | RECON_S         | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SIDEWALK | ACTIVITY_SIDEWALK | 
              +-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
              | CONSTR_SEW      | CONSTRUCT NEW SEWER           | ACTIVITY_SEWER    |
New,     ---> | RECON_S         | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SEWER    | ACTIVITY_SEWER    | 
duplicate     +-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
              | CONSTR_ROAD     | CONSTRUCT NEW ROAD            | ACTIVITY_ROAD     |
              | RECON_ROAD      | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING ROAD     | ACTIVITY_ROAD     |
              +-----------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
```

This scenario might seem silly or unlikely in the context of the sample data. But in reality, I have dozens of domains, each with dozens of values. So yes, it's all too easy for users to enter duplicate domain values between different domains.

And so, due to the `LEFT JOIN`, the `REPORT_VW` produces incorrect results:

```
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| PROJECT_ID |        DESCRIPTION            |  COST     |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
|         01 | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SIDEWALK | 5,000,000 | <--Two records for project 01 
|         01 | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING SEWER    | 5,000,000 | <  (an extra 5 million dollars) 
|         02 | CONSTRUCT NEW SEWER           | 6,000,000 |              
|         03 | CONSTRUCT NEW ROAD            | 7,000,000 |
|         04 | RECONSTRUCT EXISTING ROAD     | 8,000,000 |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
```

**Question:**

Is there anything I can do to prevent duplicate domain values being entered between domains?

Under normal circumstances, I think domains (lookup tables) would be stored in plain old database tables. A simple `unique index` or `primary key` would be used.

But I'm not so lucky. My domains are stored in an XML column in a system table.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique function-based index on the `CODE` column.

```
create table t1 (c1 clob);
```

Because your table uses CLOB based on the linked documentation.

```
insert into t1 values('<x1><p1>HELLO</p1><p2>WORLD</p2></x1>');

1 row inserted.

commit;

Commit complete.

select extractvalue(xmltype(c1), 'x1/p1') from t1;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(C1),'X1/P1')
---------------------------------
HELLO
```

Create the unique index for x1/p1:

```
create unique index i1 on t1(extractvalue(xmltype(c1), 'x1/p1'));

insert into t1 values('<x1><p1>SECOND</p1><p2>TEST</p2></x1>');
commit;

1 row inserted.

commit;

Commit complete.

select extractvalue(xmltype(c1), 'x1/p1') from t1;

EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(C1),'X1/P1')
---------------------------------
HELLO
SECOND
```

Try to insert duplicate (`p1=HELLO`) data:

```
insert into t1 values('<x1><p1>HELLO</p1><p2>TEST</p2></x1>');
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (BP.I1) violated
```